# Flutter группировка локализаций в arb файле плагина intl

Tags: flutter, dart, локализация, мобильные-приложения

Вот вопрос, у плагина intl есть JSON'ка с расширением arb. **Можно ли как-то группировать эти локали, чтобы не совать префиксы для логического разделения?**

Например, как видно на скриншоте, для экрана auth я добавляю к именам префикс auth, но, по-моему, это не сильно удобно. Как было выяснено методом "научного тыка", вложенные словари он не понимает.

[image: скриншот с моими локалями для Flutter приложения]

Comment: А вы точно хотите иметь префиксы? Как показывает опыт, это не очень удобно...

Comment: Нет, об этом и вопрос. Возможно, я неправильно выразился. Я хочу избавиться от префиксов и узнать, можно ли сгруппировать локали иначе?